# How to store int from file, to Arraylist using StringTokenizer in java?

Tags: java, file, arraylist, java-io, stringtokenizer

I have a .txt file which i want to read in my program. I have to take the values for buy and price and store them into an ArrayList of Integers. For example :

> "buy 50 price 30"

I must insert the 50 into the ArrayList buy and 30 into the ArrayList price.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Store { 

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    List <Integer> buy = new ArrayList<>();
    List <Integer> price = new ArrayList<>();

    // try to read the file
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Nets.txt"));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            line = line.replaceAll("/t", "");
            line = line.toLowerCase();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                //Don't know what to do
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: explain the problem, not only what you want to do

Comment: From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html): *"`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead."* --- Regex would be perfect for this: `"(?i)\\s*buy\\s+(\\d+)\\s+price\\s+(\\d+)\\s*"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, consider using `String.split(regex)` instead of `StringTokenizer`.

Here is what the code might look like:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.trim();
    line = line.replaceAll("/t", "");
    line = line.toLowerCase();

    // New code
    String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
    buy.add(Integer.valueOf(tokens[1]));
    price.add(Integer.valueOf(tokens[3]));
}
```

This approach also gives better performance because you do not need to iterate over unused tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Please dont ask for spoon feeding. but here you can do following

```
while (st.hasMoreTokens())  
{  
st.nextToken();  
list1.add(st.nextToken());  
st.nextToken();  
list2.add(st.nextToken());  
}
```